# 3d view fold animation iOs 5

Tags: animation, ios5, view, 3d, fold

I'm developing a iOs 5 app. I would like to animate a view with a 3d fold effect. I mean: fold de view in 3 parts, like when you fold a paper to put in an envelope. I've seen some posts but they don't explain it well. 
Someone can help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A friend linked me to this project which shows how to do the "Flipboard" style animation as well as a couple of other techniques.

https://github.com/epatel/EPGLTransitionView

This might get you started.